# extract month day and year after parsed date d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I parsed the date from json file with the function in d3.js:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m-%Y").parse;
```

and get the date as:

```
var date = "Tue Jan 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
```

Now I want to take out the month, day, and year from the variable date and print it. How do I do that?

Or you can say I need to print only month, day, and year, not the extra stuff like Tue (India standard time) etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

edit: Assuming you mean a javascript date object:

```
var date = new Date("Tue Jan 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)");
var day = date.getDay(); //returns 0 - 6
var month = date.getMonth(); //returns 0 - 11
var year = date.getFullYear(); //returns 4 digit year ex: 2000
```

Comment: no its not working because the date is not the string.. its an object.

Comment: it´s a javascript date object?

Comment: then my answer should work. The javascript date object provides some basic getter functions. see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: Find all JS Date prototype methods here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype

Comment: how to fetch the day if the value is greater then 6 i.e. may be 12 or 30?

Comment: @SaurabhSinha did you find an answer to this question? I have the same problem right now